# Timer repeated execution only execute once

Tags: java, swing, schedule, timertask

I'm have an intended task that is supposed to execute every 10 seconds. It works when I just run the project, meaning, it will run() once, but it will not the subsequent time. Can someone tell me which part is wrong..I spent hours trying to remedy this problem but to no avail :(
This is my main:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    launch(TestingApp.class, args);


    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Cost(), 10*1000, 10*1000);}
```

This is the Cost code:

```
public class Cost extends TimerTask {

   public void run() {
      Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();
      Integer hour = rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

      if (hour == 3) {
         try {

            File file = new File("D:/TESTAPP/Testing.csv");
            if (file != null) {
               Opencsv csv = new Opencsv();

               csv.Csvreader();

            }
         } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cost.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         }
      }

      else {

      }
   }
}
```

Some of the methods I tried was ending a thread.sleep to the end of Cost code, and the other method I tried was added a while(true) my main...

Comment: nice "creative" indentation style.

Comment: How is that related to solving the problem?

Comment: If you want us to be able to help you, it's in your best interest not to make it hard for us to read and understand your code. We're all volunteers, and if you ask us to put in the effort, you should do the same.

Comment: Possible problem: your csv.Csvreader(); is blocking the thread. Do this in a background thread.

Comment: sorry about that, I thought by indenting the different blocks will make it much easier to read, maybe it's just my perspective. Ok, I will take a look at the csvreader

Comment: Yes, indenting correctly does make code easier to read, but yours is all over the place. You'll want to look at a Java specification to see how to format your code better so that a) other's will understand it better, and more importantly, b) your future self will understand it better.

Comment: You don't want to get rid of all indentations for gorsh sake, just bad indentation. :o   Also, what does your question have to do with coding with Swing (your question has a "Swing" tag)?

Comment: Nevermind, I'll just edit your post myself.

Comment: Please have a look here: [Geosoft Java Programming Style Guidelines](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that this:

```
Opencsv csv = new Opencsv();
csv.Csvreader();
```

is blocking the timer's thread. Have you tried doing this in a background thread?

For example, your code is equivalent to this:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TestTimer {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
           System.out.println("here");
           try {
              Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
         }
      }, 1000, 1000);
   }
}
```

I'm suggesting that instead you do the inner stuff in a background thread so as not to slow the Timer down. Note the different times of execution of this:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class TestTimer {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Timer timer = new Timer();
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                  System.out.println("here");
                  try {
                     Thread.sleep(10 * 1000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
               }
            }).start();
         }
      }, 1000, 1000);
   }
}
```

**Edit 2**
Again, your question has a "swing" tag suggesting that your question involves code that is part of a Swing GUI. If so, then the recommendations may need to be different, especially if any of your code needs to be called on the Swing event thread.

Comment: ok, I'm still figuring this out...I'm new to background threading, let me try to incorporate to my code

Comment: @EugeneWong: again, your question has a "swing" tag suggesting that your question involves code that is part of a Swing GUI. If so, then the recommendations may need to be different, especially if any of your code needs to be called on the Swing event thread.

Comment: Ah..I managed to understand and got it working. Thanks alot! I really appreciate your help! I can finally sleep at last after hours on this. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, I'm using swing for gui, but I'm really noob to this at the moment. I followed through a netbean tutorial on quick gui. I'm currently getting some codes, and later on integrate into the swing gui codes

Comment: @EugeneWong: then my answer may not be correct. You understand that  your question uses a java.util.Timer, and that Swing has its own Timer class, javax.swing.Timer. There's a good chance that you may be better off using a Swing Timer so that code that needs to be called on Swing's event thread is called on the event thread.

Comment: oh boy, yep, I noticed the javax.swing.timer in the swing codes. Ok I will try to use the swing timer. I think I will continue it later in the day..it's 5am now. Do you mind if I ask you again if I encounter any problems with the integrating with swing?

Comment: Yes, we'd all be happy to help. You probably should start a new question so as not to confuse the issue.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels +1 endless patience, with my respect `We're all volunteers, and if you ask us to put in the effort, you should`,